Calling the ctor of Derived class with the parameters of ctor off the Base class
Browsing my code I found a part which - I thought - should be a compile time error, but in reality in compiles and runs fine. A simplified version is:
class Base
{
public:
   Base(int i)
   {}
};


class Derived : public Base
{
public:
   //using Base::Base;
};


int main()
{
    Derived obj{ 5 };
}

Checking the code snippet in cppinsights, for the line inside main it generates Derived obj = {Base(5)}; when using c++17 or newer and does not compile with c++14 or older.
In c++14 if I uncomment //using Base::Base; then the code compiles. This using here is available since C++11 I believe. In this case cppinsights generates Derived obj = Derived{5};. I can understand the meaning of it.
My questions are

Why does the original code compiles with c++17. What is name of the feature?
What does {Base(5)}; mean? What are the curly brackets are used for?
Does it have anything to do with using Base::Base; or they are completely different.

Thank you for your help!
EDIT1:
I changed the main() function to the lines below, just to show what cppinsights "creates" from it
int main()
{
    Derived obj1{ 5 }; // OK. cppinsights: Derived obj1 = {Base(5)};
    Derived obj2 = {Base(5)}; // OK. cppinsights: {Base(Base(5))};
    //Derived obj3 = Base{5}; // error: no viable conversion from 'Base' to 'Derived'
}


Let's start with the second question.
Derived obj{ 5 }; is the list-initialization syntax. The first (and only) expression on that list is used to initialize the Base member, which requires one conversion (from int to Base).
Now, since C++17 Derived is an aggregate, which means that the list-initialization syntax now uses aggregate initialization. In C++14, the (public) base class prevented Derived from being an aggregate.
In C++14, the using statement allowed the Base ctors to participate in overload resolution when constructing a Derived object. Base::Base(int) obviously wins the overload resolution for Derived{5}.

Thank you! To summarize (and check if I understand): Derived obj{ 5 }; is list-initialization and since c++17 my Derived class is an aggregate ("no base classes (until C++17)" was changed to no virtual and no private / protected direct base classes.) so it can be initialized - well - like an aggregate because int can be converted to Base (because I didn't mark the ctor of Base explicit).

In my original post the second half of my 2nd question, I meant I don't know the meaning of the outer curly braces in the "generated" code of cppinsigths: Derived obj1 = {Base(5)}; (The first non-whitespace character after the equal sign) I guess this is the way how cppinsights shows that an int (in my example: 5) is casted to Base when using list-initialization. But when I write Derived obj2 = {Base(5)}; cppinsights shows Derived obj2 = {Base(Base(5))}; as I mentioned it in my edited post. ("EDIT1")

I don't know about the first two but using statement is related with Inheriting constructors. It is used when one wants to inherit base class's constructor and doesn't bother with initializing derived class's data members. More detailed explanation can be found in the link.
As with the first two questions; I have no idea why it works after C++17 without using statement or why it only works with {} but not ().
